# Multitenency in Apache Nifi

Tags: multi-tenant, apache-nifi

I am working on a cloud based application using Apache Nifi, for this we required to support Multitenency. But the current Nifi implementation only supports role based access for users, for a single flow.

I could understand that the flow state is saved as a single compressed XML file for a Nifi instance. So that who ever logins into that instance can view the same flow. Our requirement is to create unique flows for each user login. I tried to replicate state saving gz XML file for each users, but couldn't succeeded as the FlowService/FlowController which loads the XML file, is instantiated at the application startup and they are singleton. Please correct me, if Iam wrong with this approach. Or is there any other solution for adding Multitenant support with Nifi. I also wonder the reason behind the Nifi as a single user application.

Answer (score 6):

Multi-tenant support will be introduced in Apache NiFi 1.0.0. There is a BETA release available [1]. This will support assigning permissions on a per component basis. However, the different tenants still share a canvas. There has been discussions of introducing a workspace concept that could provide visually separate dataflows.

[1] https://nifi.apache.org/download.html

Comment: thanks Matt, I already took the latest source code 1.0.0-Snapshot and started modifying it. However we need to support multiple DFM's in the same Nifi instance with complete separation of DataFlows, ie the visually separate dataflows. Thats why I tried to create seperate flow.xml.gz file for each user login.

Comment: @Krishna just to let you know, you can create different process groups on the root process group and assign permissions to isolate various tenants on the system. Thus, each "DFM" would have access to their own PG and no others. If the DFM exits their PG to the root, they will not have access to any other, so there will be no visual confusion. Hope this helps.